# Repeated server function implementation for various users

Tags: node.js, express, single-sign-on, backend

I have a node.js application for which I am implementing a custom SSO login system. How it works is that it takes GET parameters of the user (username, real name and email) as well as a signature that was produced by an API on my other server. What my code is supposed to do is take the user's url GET parameters, concatenate them, and then encrypt them with the private key. Then, it would compare the encrypted result to the signature. If it is equal, it returns true and the user is logged in. My code is below.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if(!signedIn){
  try{
    var user = req.query.username;
    var name = req.query.realName;
    var email = req.query.email;
    var signature = req.query.signature;
    var encrypted = crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.privateKey).update(user + name + email).digest('hex');
    if(encrypted == signature){
      username = user;
      signedIn = true;
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view/index.html');
    }else{
      res.redirect("https://infinia.press/sso/login")
    }
  }catch(error){
    res.redirect("https://infinia.press/sso/login")
  }
  }
  else{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view/index.html')
  }
});
```

However, I realised that this would not work, as the server code only runs once. This means that if more than one user signs in, it would cause errors. How can I call this function every time the url is visited?

Comment: That code runs once, yes, but for each request. This means the code you have there will run once, everytime a GET is performed to the '/' route of your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A route is defined for telling the server what to do **everytime** an action  (GET,POST,PUT,...) is performed in that route, and not only once.

In this example, everytime a GET is performed to this server @ port 3000 a counter will increase and the server will respond with the current number of requests served.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var totalRequests = 0;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  totalRequests++
  res.send('Hello Request #'+totalRequests)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have made a global variable I guess.